# How to get rid of the "Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps" Warning on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried making an IF statement checking if mounted wasn't true and then returning nothing, but didn't worked for this situation, then I tried to make the Navigator only be activated if the Widget is still mounted, but this didn't removed the warning too.

Here's my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:agil_app/Helpers/notification_helper.dart';
import 'package:agil_app/constants/size_config.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:agil_app/Module/Localizacao/localizacao_notifier.dart';

class IntroAgil extends StatefulWidget {
  const IntroAgil({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<IntroAgil> createState() => _IntroAgilState();
}

class _IntroAgilState extends State<IntroAgil> {
  bool geoPermission = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 100,
                height: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 100,
                child: FlareActor(
                  "assets/flr/IntroAgil.flr",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  animation: "IntroAgil",
                  callback: (callback) async {
                    await handleAsyncTasks();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> handleAsyncTasks() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);

    geoPermission =
        await Provider.of<LocalizacaoNotifier>(context, listen: false)
            .permissionLocator();

    if (!geoPermission) {
      geoPermission =
          await Provider.of<LocalizacaoNotifier>(context, listen: false)
              .requestPermission();
    }

    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do a if(context.mounted){} in those bloacks

Answer (score 0):

On your widget, don't call the function like this

```
callback: (callback) async {
            await handleAsyncTasks();
          },
```

Just call the function

```
callback: handleAsyncTasks,
```

Because when flutter build the widget, it cannot wait the async